# Java adjustedAverage in array

Tags: java, arrays, average

i'm having trouble searching for an error in my code, i have to calculate the average of the average of each row without using the ones that don't meet a critery, depending of the percentage excluded, for example, in the followed example we have 9 rows. If we exclude the 15 % that means that we have to discard the first row and the last row.

```
int [][] m={// row average
{1,3,1,3}, //2
{5,6,7,8,9},// 7
{7},//7
{6,7,6,7},//6.5
{6,5,6,5},//5.5
{9,9},//9
{4,4,3,8,6},// 5
{400,4}, //202
{8,8,6,8,10}};//8

// average of row averages 28.0 (not adjusted)
// adjusted average depends on percentage excluded
```

This is just an array example.

```
public static double adjustedAverage (int[][] m,int percentageExcluded){

double average[]= new double[m.length];
double excluded = m.length*percentageExcluded/100.;
double suma=0;
double cantidad=0;
double averageResult;

//creamos un array con las medias de cada fila
for (int fila=0; fila < m.length;fila++){

  int rowTotales=0;
  for (int columna=0; columna <m[fila].length;columna++){

    rowTotales += m[fila][columna];
  }

  average[fila]= rowTotales / m[fila].length;  
}
```

This part i already know that is correct, i created a new array with the average of each row.

```
//ordenamos el array
Arrays.sort(average);
```

In this part i order the array to exclude the biggest and lowest average

```
//Calculamos la nueva media excluyendo los que no cumplen las condiciones
for (int columna=0;columna < average.length;columna++){

  if (columna>=excluded && columna<=average.length-(excluded)){suma=suma+average[columna];
    cantidad++;}
}

averageResult = suma/cantidad;
 System.out.println("La mediana ajustada es"+averageResult);
return averageResult;
```

In the example above with a percentageExcluded of 15 % the result must be 6.8, but my program prints 7. Any idea where i failed?

Comment: You need to debug your code.

Comment: Also please use English names wherever possible since when I see variables in foreign language the first thing I do is I go to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you actually have two problems here.

Your main problem is the behaviour of Java in handling primitives. My suggestion is to always cast every int into a double before mathematical operations among int and double. This is also necessary if you have just ints in your equation and expect the result to be a double!

Please, have a look at your code. I've added the missing casts.

Having solved this issue leads to your second problem. Because starting this code shows, that you throw away 3 of 9 instead of 2 of 9 rows. You have to adjust the way to drop the right amount of rows, concerning the percentage you mentioned in your description.

Just run the code as is and look at the output in the console. You expect the sum to be 48, but you only have 43 then.

Good Luck! ;)

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    int [][] m={// row average
            {1,3,1,3}, //2
            {5,6,7,8,9},// 7
            {7},//7
            {6,7,6,7},//6.5
            {6,5,6,5},//5.5
            {9,9},//9
            {4,4,3,8,6},// 5
            {400,4}, //202
            {8,8,6,8,10}};//8

    adjustedAverage(m, 15);

}

public static double adjustedAverage (int[][] m,int percentageExcluded){

    double average[]= new double[m.length];
    double excluded = ((double)m.length * (double)percentageExcluded) / 100.00; // <<<<< cast int to double
    double suma=0;
    double cantidad=0;
    double averageResult;

    // <<<<< the value of excluded (just for debugging purposes)
    System.out.println("excluded: " + excluded);


    //creamos un array con las medias de cada fila
    for (int fila=0; fila < m.length;fila++){

      double rowTotales = 0; 

      for (int columna=0; columna <m[fila].length;columna++){

        rowTotales += (double)m[fila][columna]; // <<<<<< cast int to double
      }

      average[fila]= rowTotales / (double)m[fila].length; // <<<<<< cast int to double
    }

    //ordenamos el array
    Arrays.sort(average);

    // the list of averages (just for debugging purposes)
    System.out.println("List of averages: ");
    for(int i=0; i<average.length; i++)
    {   
    System.out.println(average[i]);
    }

    //Calculamos la nueva media excluyendo los que no cumplen las condiciones
    for (int columna=0;columna < average.length;columna++){

      if (columna>=excluded && (columna<=average.length-excluded))
      {
          // <<<<< every relevant average (just for debugging purposes)
          System.out.println("relevant average for 'suma': " + average[columna]);

          suma += average[columna];
          cantidad++;
      }
    }

    // <<<<< the sum of all relevant averages (just for debugging purposes)
    System.out.println("Suma: " + suma);

    averageResult = suma/cantidad;
    System.out.println("La mediana ajustada es " + averageResult);

    return averageResult;

}
```